# Submitting parallel jobs on CentOS

Tags: parallel-processing, centos6, task-queue

I am trying to submit a parallel job on CentOS 6.8 machine with 3 nodes. Is there a queueing system and how to use it (want to specify a number of nodes used and a number of threads per node used, etc...)?
Any good resource/link to start learning from?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel is a very simple solution: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-queue-system-batch-manager

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's useful as I am dealing with a very small cluster.